# Return json array in php

Tags: php, arrays, slim

I am trying to `return` a json array in php.
This is what I tried but only return my first variable

```
return $this->response->withJson(array($todos, $fecha_baja));
```

my `$todos` variable is this

```
$todos = $sth->fetchObject();
```

and my `$fecha_baja`

```
$rfbaja=$sth1->fetchObject():
$fecha_baja=$rfbaja->fecha_baja;
```

but the only thing im getting from the return is the info from `$todos`
Does anyone know how can i `return` both `$todos` and `$fecha_baja`

Comment: Please provide example data for your input, and expected JSON for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
return $this->response->withJson(['todos' => $todos, 'fecha' => $fecha_baja]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it, just one more question, if i want to access a property from the client side, i should do todos.property?

Comment: your question is little unclear, but if my intuition is correct, yes you may want to access the todos property from the response object separately. and that depends on which client are you using. if this answer helped you, make it the accepted answer, upvote would be also  nice :)